# Access exception information within a `contextlib.contextmanager`

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this simple context manager:

```py
class ModuleNotFoundIgnore:
    """Context manager to ignore ModuleNotFoundErrors."""
    def __enter__(self): ...

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type is ModuleNotFoundError:
            return True
```

I'm trying to use

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
```

to write an equivalent context manager, but there's something I'm missing.

Example of use...

When all goes well, code is executed normally:

```py
    >>> with ModuleNotFoundIgnore():
    ...     import os.path  # test when the module exists
    ...     # The following code is reached and executed
    ...     print('hi there!') # code is reached
    ...
    hi there!
```

But if you try to import a module that doesn't exist on your system,
the block will be skipped from that point onward, silently.

```
    >>> with ModuleNotFoundIgnore():
    ...     import do.i.exist
    ...     # The following code is NEVER reached or executed
    ...     print(do.i.exist)
    ...     t = 0 / 0
```

But if there's any other kind of error (other than ModuleNotFoundError that is,
the error will be raised normally.

```py
    >>> with ModuleNotFoundIgnore():
    ...     t = 0/0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      ...
    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

### My (failing) solution

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

@contextmanager
def ModuleNotFoundIgnore():
    yield
    exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    if exc_type is ModuleNotFoundError:
        return True
```

The reason is that `sys.exc_info()` always gives me `(None, None, None)`: But how else am I supposed to get access to the `exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb` triple I need?

Comment: What exactly is your goal here?  If you want to resume execution after a line within the `with` block that generated a specific error, that's not going to happen - context managers don't have that level of control over the code.

Comment: Simple: the class I mentioned does something context managers definitely can do (access exception information). I was wondering IF and if so HOW one could do the same using the contextmanager decorator.